# PHP getting out of 'if' condition and continue the next part

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, goto

I am now implementing a Ajax and the server side programming language is PHP.
I need to create a Ajax form verifying and input system for my web app.

```
$redirectPage = $redirectTime = '';

if($a == 'register') {
    $data = array('name', 'username', 'password', 'gender', 'emailaddress');
    $required = array('name', 'username', 'password');

    foreach($data as $field) {
        if(in_array($field, $required) && (!isset($_POST[$field]) || $_POST[$field] == '')) {
            $type = 'danger';
            $message = 'Please enter all required fields.';
            // *1
        } else {
            $$field = $_POST[$field];
        }
    }

    // Continue with register process
    // Set the redirectPage and redirectTime for JavaScript setTimeout here
} else {
    $type = 'warning';
    $message = 'You usually won\'t be able to see this. But if you did, that means you are trying to hack my website!';
    return;
}

$retval = json_encode(
    array(
        'Type' => $type,
        'Message' => alert($type, $message), // my own function, not important here
        'RedirectPage' => $redirectPage,
        'RedirectTime' => $redirectTime,
    )
);

echo $retval; // The value here will send back to my Ajax
```

As you see I didn't stopped the handle process even though the post field is not in the required array. Finally it will continue with the rest process.

**For *1:**
This is the place I have tried to put some reserved words here.

**continue:** For an experienced programmer, you should be noticed that it will only get out of this if condition and continue the next foreach loop.

**exit:** The rest of the code won't process, by all means nothing to return to my Ajax until its timed out.

**break:** I thought it will get out of

```
if($a == 'register')
```

but it didn't happened.

**goto:** I don't want to be eaten by dinosaurs except its the only way to do that.

For the rest of the code add an if condition check whether

```
$type
```

has been set to 'danger':

 I don't wanna do this way ... (But if this is the only way ...)

Thank you.

Comment: did the  dinosaur eat the question? because i don't get what you are asking.

Comment: @Dagon I think the op wants to break out of the if but I am not 100% sure because it is badly formatted question

Comment: Are you trying to see if all the fields are used in the $_POST array, you could use array_diff_key or array_intersect_key to do that

Comment: What i am gonna do is: Once inside the if condition, if I found any errors, it will stop processing the rest of the if condition and continue to the next part of code.

Comment: And sorry for my bad English as I am not a native speaker :(\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, but I believe the issue you're having can be solved by adding some scope. I refactored your code in hopes that it will point you to the right direction.

```
function sendResponse ($type, $message, $redirectPage, $redirectTime) {

    $retval = json_encode(
        array(
            'Type' => $type,
            'Message' => alert($type, $message), // my own function, not important here
            'RedirectPage' => $redirectPage,
            'RedirectTime' => $redirectTime,
        )
    );

    echo $retval; // The value here will send back to my Ajax
}

function sendRequiredResponse ($redirectPage, $redirectTime) {

    $type = 'danger';
    $message = 'Please enter all required fields.';

    sendResponse($type, $message, $redirectPage, $redirectTime);
}

function sendHackResponse ($redirectPage, $redirectTime) {

    $type = 'warning';
    $message = 'You usually won\'t be able to see this. But if you did, that means you are trying to hack my website!';

    sendResponse($type, $message, $redirectPage, $redirectTime);
}

function sendRegisteredResponse ($redirectPage, $redirectTime) {

    $type = 'success';
    $message = 'Registration successfull';

    sendResponse($type, $message, $redirectPage, $redirectTime);
}

function register($redirectPage, $redirectTime) {

    $data = array('name', 'username', 'password', 'gender', 'emailaddress');
    $required = array('name', 'username', 'password');

    foreach($data as $field) {

        if(in_array($field, $required) && (!isset($_POST[$field]) || $_POST[$field] == '')) {

            /**** registration stops *****/
            return sendRequiredResponse($redirectPage, $redirectTime);
        }

        $$field = $_POST[$field];
    }

    // Continue with register process
    // Set the redirectPage and redirectTime for JavaScript setTimeout here

    sendRegisteredResponse($redirectPage, $redirectTime);
}

$redirectPage = $redirectTime = '';

if($a === 'register') {
    register($redirectPage, $redirectTime);
} else {
    sendHackResponse($redirectPage, $redirectTime);
}
```

Comment: That seems to work, I am gonna try it and let you know the result. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want if you truly want to break out of an if is a do while loop

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

From the first example on the documentation page

```
<?php
do {
    if ($i < 5) {
        echo "i is not big enough";
        break;
    }
    $i *= $factor;
    if ($i < $minimum_limit) {
        break;
    }
   echo "i is ok";

    /* process i */

} while (0);
?>
```

However I don't see this used much as there is usually a better way to structure the code.

Goto can be used too, but I see this even less often
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

If you are just wanting to check that all the fields are present `isset` in the $_POST you can do array_diff

```
 $required = array('name', 'username', 'password');
 $missing = array_diff( $required, array_keys($_POST) );
```

if you need to check for empty you can use `array_filter` on the `$_POST` but it will count `0` as empty too, but you could make a simple function to fix that, and then do array_diff,

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

- Returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

By using an array of required keys as array1, and array_keys( $_POST ) as array2 we can get the difference of the keys, if the return contains any items they are present in the required array ( array1 ) but not the $_POST.

By using `array_filter($_POST)` we can remove empty items from the post array and then do the diff will indicate these items have no value, however array_filter will remove `false, '', 0` valued items from the array.  You can make a simple function

```
array_filter( $_POST, function($item){ return $item !== ''; });
```

To filter the empty strings only.

So putting that all to gather you get something like this

```
$required = array('name', 'username', 'password');
$missing = array_diff(
    $required,
    array_filter(
        $_POST,
        function($item){
            return $item !== '';
        }
    )
); 

if( count( $missing ) > 0 ){
    echo 'missing fields: '. implode(', ', $missing );
}
```